# Comando firebase init com mensagem de erro (Cannot read property 'projectId' of undefined)

Tags: firebase

Estou tentando usar o Firebase CLI Tools para criar um serviço de hospedagem de site, mas está retornando uma mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectId' of undefined

Seguem os detalhes:

**Sistema Operacional:**
Windows 10

**Comando executado:**

```
firebase init --debug
```

**Retorno esperado:**
Criar arquivos de configuração `firebase.json` na raiz do projeto.

**Resultado obtido:**

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:
D:\projetos\portfolio_project\jobs\templates

[info]
=== Project Setup
[info]
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info]
[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:51.589Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects?page_size=100

[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:53.158Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-10-18T15:03:53.795Z] TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectId' of undefined
at C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\init\features\project.js:48:23
at arrayMap (C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:639:23)
at Function.map (C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9556:14)
at C:\Users\adrie\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\init\features\project.js:46:21
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[error]
[error] Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Um alerta para quem tem 2 ou mais contas no google**, ao acessar a firebase cli e tentar acessar um projeto, certificar-se de q a conta usada na cli tenha um projeto firebase criado.

Esse foi o problema. Com 2 ou mais contas google, e tentar acessar através da cli a conta q não possui projeto firebase invariavelmente não funciona!

Por essa razão não encontrava o 'projectId', não tinha projeto algum!!

É apenas um lapso de atenção, mas te trava por algum tempo!!